# Scheduled tasks won't run simple command

Tags: sound, cron

The command below works fine in terminal but won't run using the gnome scheduled tasks.

```
pacmd set-sink-volume 0 42768
```

Comment: Not an answer, but cron runs with a limited set of environment variables (as you can read here:http://serverfault.com/questions/337631/crontab-execution-doesnt-have-the-same-environment-variables-as-executing-user), you will probably need to export some, as you can read here: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/FAQ/#index5h3

Comment: I was able to use the command amixer in stead of pacmd. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Answered by OP in comments.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509611/scheduled-tasks-wont-run-simple-command#comment688569_509611)

> I was able to use the command amixer in stead of pacmd. Thanks